# php errors are shown after being trimmed

Tags: php, magento

I am running a WAMP installation with php, and am trying to run magento development environment on it. Now during development I am getting a lot of errors as expected, but the problem is that these errors are being trimmed before display, so I am seeing something like below.

```
wamp\www\kenp\devmagento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage\Co...', 'F:\wamp\www\ken...', 93, Array)
#1 F:\wamp\www\kenp\devmagento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Core_Model...');
```

As you can see the file paths are being trimmed with `...`, and it's a real pain to debug. Any idea how to get it to show complete messages and not trim those paths?

Answer (score 1):

First off, i want to strongly suggest using xdebug. Since i always use it, I only know of xdebug settings for error length etc: http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace#var_display_max_data. Probably there will be something similar in the php.ini config.

Comment: I already have xdebug installed as it comes natively with wamp. But for some reason these errors are being shown as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the error log in var/log/exception.log for details, make sure you have enabled the logging from backend.